# Why do I still getting error, Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-volume

I have installed docker inside my EC2 instance and running Jenkins as a docker container. The complete code is given below.

```
sudo su
apt-get update 
apt install -y docker.io 
service docker start 
usermod -a -G docker ubuntu
chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock 
mkdir /data
mkdir /data/jenkins
chmod o+rwx /data
chmod o+rwx /data/jenkins
```

Then to run the container,

```
docker run --name jenkins-dev -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /data/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins:jdk11
```

An then I entered inside the container by `docker exec -it 17cfbb0f966d` and install docker inside it as mentioned over [here](https://faun.pub/how-to-install-docker-in-jenkins-container-4c49ba40b373). Then, the docker commands were working fine. But after re logging I can't run docker commands. It gives below error `Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`. I guess, after every login the permission for docker.sock file is changing. So i had to rerun `chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock` in main terminal to work docker commands inside the container. But I tried another way to add user jenkins into docker group as well. It was successfully added to group "docker" as shown below.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-133-184-31:~$ docker exec -it 17cfbb0f966d bash
jenkins@17cfbb0f966d:/$ grep /etc/group -e "docker"
docker:x:999:jenkins
```

After that i rebooted the instance and started the container again. But still I can't run any docker commands inside the container. It throws the same error.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-133-184-31:~$ docker exec -it 17cfbb0f966d bash
jenkins@17cfbb0f966d:/$ docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix 
/var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

What may be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked after running the container as root user ie: `docker run -u root ...`

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem several days ago and fixed it by adding an another group as below:

```
RUN useradd -u $UID -ms /bin/bash $USER && \
  usermod -aG docker $USER && \
  groupadd -g $DGID dockerr && \
  usermod -aG dockerr $USER
```

The `$DGID` here is the `gid` of group `docker` at the host.

After installing docker client inside the docker image, a `docker` group is created, but the `gid` of this docker group could be different from that at host, while the `gid`, not the group name is the key.

So I created a new group with the `gid` of docker group at host and put my new user into this group. With this `gid`, this user then can access the  `/var/run/docker.sock`.

PS.

I tried to make the `docker` group inside docker share the same `gid` with the host, but just couldn't make it.

This did fix my problem, however I'm wondering whether there could be a better solution.